# Normalize slashes in path on Linux

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems, redhat

What is the recommended way to specify to use native separators in filesystem path object?

Below is a simple example with a static string.

```
std::string str = "/tmp\\foo";
std::filesystem::path path(str);
std::cout << "Generic_string:" << path.generic_string() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Make_preferred:" << path.make_preferred() << std::endl;
```

This will output

```
Generic_string:/tmp\foo
Make_preferred:/tmp\foo
```

The make_preferred method does not appear to make any change to path. Do I really need to use std::replace to fix the issue?

Comment: ``\`` is a valid symbol in filenames on Linux, so in general you can't assume it to be a separator, me thinks.

Comment: I'll add that since forward slash '/' will work with the Windows API, there is no reason not to use it everywhere.

Comment: Michael: Agree but in this case the path is constructed by data found in an externally produced text file. So outside our control.